# Увеличить время задержки для блока

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как возможно и вообще возможно ли увеличить время hover`a, т.е. при наведении на слово "Магия" появляется скрытый блок "lorem ipsum", как увеличить саму задержку этого блока, чтобы не зависимо от положения курсора он не пропадал секунд 30

Заранее спасибо!

```css
.block{
  color: black;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px; height: 30px;
  display: none;
}

.div1{
  font-size: 50px;
  color: black;
}

.div1:hover ~ .block{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">Магия</div>
<div class="block">lorem ipsum</div>
```

Comment: Попробуй у .block указать - transition: display 1s ease-out 30s;

Comment: К сожалению не работает((

Comment: Нужно решение без JS?

Comment: Если другого пути не будет, давайте с JS, я просто начинающий в верстке и до JS пока не дошел

Comment: @Анкор добавил ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Совсем простой вариант, если такой элемент на странице будет только один то в принципе подойдет, если же таких будет много, функцию нужно переделать.

```js
foo();
function foo() {
  let div1 = document.querySelector('.div1');
      if(!div1) return;
  let block = document.querySelector('.block');
  let timeout = 30000; // Время задержки в миллисекундах
  
  // При наведении на div1
  div1.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
    // Показываем block
    block.style.display = 'block';
    // Через заданное время скрываем его
    setTimeout(() => block.style.display = 'none', timeout);
  });
}
```

```css
.block{
  color: black;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px; height: 30px;
  display: none;
}

.div1{
  font-size: 50px;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">Магия</div>
<div class="block">lorem ipsum</div>
```

Comment: Да,все работает,спасибо вам!)

Answer (score 2):

Если надо через CSS, то можно попробовать зайти через прозрачность и размеры.

```
.block {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0s ease-out 21s, opacity 1s ease-out 20s;
}
.div1:hover ~ .block {
    opacity: 1;
    height: 30px;
    width: 100px;
    transition: all 0s ease-out 0s;
}
```